# jquery validate dynamically change min value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have validation on form field which works ok. When I click on element in page, I take value of it, put it into form field and I want to change min value in validation to this value
I tried rules method but it looks it is not working, but no error is shown

this is my validation call

```
$('form').validate({
lang: 'sk',
rules: {
  'payment[amount]': {
    min: 1
  }
},
highlight: function(element) {
  $(element).parent().addClass('state-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
  $(element).parent().removeClass('state-error');
}
```

});

and this is my function running when I click on element

```
 $( "rewardbox" ).click(function() {
  $val = $( this ).children("amount").text();
  $num = parseInt($val);
  $("#payment_amount").val($num);
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

  $( "#form" ).rules( "remove", "min" );
  $("#form").rules("add", {
      'payment[amount]':{
      min: function ()  { return $("#payment_amount").val()  }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to put as min value directly my variable $num but no luck

how this should work?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `.rules()` method, it does not get attached the `form` element.  It only gets attached to the `input` field where you're attaching the new rule.

Since you would attach `.rules()` to the input itself, you do not declare the input name inside of it.  As per the docs, just `key:value` pairs of the rules being added or removed and/or a custom `messages` object.

```
$("#payment_amount").rules("remove", "min");
$("#payment_amount").rules("add", {
    min: 2 
});
```

[Please refer to usage examples in the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Answer (score 0):

have you placed validations after click function ..

i mean

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// click function (in click function append required value to a hidden field)

// then add validation (in validation min: function ()  { return $("#payment_amount").val()  } this will work )

});
```

Comment: updated with new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/medashiva/5RrGa/1635/  need to add class to the form input field.

Comment: this last works when I click on submit...not what I was looking for exactly but at least something..thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105690/discussion-between-shiva-and-mi-ro).